# Nós precisamos dessas tags?

Tags: debate, tags

Esta pergunta originalmente dizia respeito a uma tag específica que era potencialmente desnecessária. Incluirei aqui mais algumas para julgamento da comunidade.

- [acentuação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o) - o wiki diz que a menos que seja uma pergunta específica sobre acentos, deve-se utilizar a tag [unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode). Sugiro que se use [encoding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding), por ser o real assunto envolvido, a menos que a pergunta seja realmente sobre Unicode. E que a tag [acentuação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acentua%c3%a7%c3%a3o) seja acentuadamente eliminada.
- [classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classes) - acho que é redundante com [oop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop). Pode ser transformada em sinônimo.
- [condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) - por relevância
- [duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) - por relevância
- [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/literal) - por relevância
- [main](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/main) - por relevância
- [option](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) - ambígua e potencialmente com problema de relevância.
- [posicionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posicionamento) - por relevância
- [when](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/when) - uma única pergunta e sem wiki, além de problema de relevância.

**Pergunta original**

Eu não vejo como "duplicados" poderia ser um assunto relevante o suficiente para merecer sua própria tag.

A tag não tem nada descritivo. E embora ter que lidar com coisas repetidas seja um problema comum, mas se mantivermos esse tipo de tag, logo teremos tags para coisas tão irrelevantes quanto "identação", "autocomplete", "herança", "concatenação" (acabei de ver que essa existe), etc.

Comment: Pior que isso só triplicados ou Nplicados :D

Comment: Precisa de uma limpeza generalizada de *tags*.

Comment: @bigown Concordo. Seria bom ter uma lista, pra organizar o movimento de limpeza.

Comment: Talvez seja difícil todo mundo concordar com o que é exagero ou não. Pra mim [tag:duplicados] não quer dizer nada, mas [tag:herança] é de extrema importância, [tag:concatenação] não é de toda ruim. Só pra ficar nesses exemplos. ter uma *tag* ou algumas *tags* para identificar algum tipo de duplicação pode ser interessante, o problema dessa é que ela não diz nada, não sei nem sobre que duplicação está falando.

Comment: @Gabe como assim uma lista?

Comment: @JorgeB. Um post no meta que listasse todas as tags problemáticas atualmente, pra que a comunidade e a moderação pudessem lidar com elas de uma só vez. Se existem mais tags que devem ser avaliadas, então vamos trabalhar nisso...

Comment: Por que não fazer isso neste post?

Comment: @Renan Problema nenhum

Comment: @Gabe boa ideia. Eu perguntei porque no PL foi uma trabalheira desgraçada.

Comment: @Renan Essa é uma má ideia. Uma lista aberta e infinita dessas ajuda muito pouco a tomar decisões. Se a gente tem tags problemáticas, a melhor coisa a fazer era listar todas num post, explicando o problema com elas. E aí a comunidade pode dizer se concorda ou não com a lista.

Comment: @Gabe entendo. Vou reverter a alteração.

Comment: @Renan Acho a lista que você fez o caminho correto. Só tiraria a sugestão de adicionar mais tags ao post.

Comment: Tag sem descrição já não é um problema?

Comment: @ismael nem sempre. Talvez com o tempo a descrição seja adicionada.

Comment: Embora já tenha respondido mencionando isso, @Gabe acho que da próxima vez, seria melhor discutir as tags de forma individual igual é feito no SOen. Isso evita que uma tag que deve ser removida seja ignorada por causa de várias outras que não devem, ou vice-versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não vejo problema algum em termos um montão de *tags*. Temos que ver quais causam problema real ao site. Se a pessoa não tiver domínio sobre o domínio (:P) dela, terá dificuldades em avaliar sua utilidade.

Temos 3 categorias básicas:

- Sinônimos - *tags* que no fundo falam da mesma coisa. Não é o caso de [classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classes) e [oop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop), ou [acentuação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acentua%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e [unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode) e [encoding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding), só para citar exemplos. Não tem nada de redundância nelas. Existe muito caso de ter versões em inglês e português.
- Ambíguas - Existem casos de uma *tag* sendo usadas para várias coisas. [duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicados) é ruim por causa disto. O correto é ter *tags* mais específicas indicando o tipo de duplicação que está se falando ali. Não é o caso de só remover a *tag*, é o caso de substituir por outras melhores.
- Irrelevantes - Tenho sérias dúvidas se as *tags* ditas irrelevantes na pergunta são de fato. Algumas podem ser porque eu não entendo do assunto. Mas duvido. Ter pouca utilidade é diferente de irrelevância. A [programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) era irrelevante.

Tem um outro problema que precisa ser avaliado - provavelmente caso a caso. Um dele é a [princípios-de-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/princ%c3%adpios-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Ele tende a ser usada, assim como qualquer outra que tenha a palavra `programação` como substituta da *tag* acima já defenestrada. O problema dela é que a pessoa usa como se fosse [sou-principiante-em-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sou-principiante-em-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Tem uma ou pergunta com ela que fala dos princípios de programação de fato. Fico pensando se vale a pena ter uma *tag* que é tão mal usada para ajudar pouco uma ou outra pergunta.

O nosso maior problema é o uso errado de *tags*. Esse eu não sei se há um boa solução.

Devemos nos concentrar nos casos óbvios e que causam problemas.

Eu provavelmente serei contra qualquer lista fechada de *tags*. Sempre terá alguma *tag* que eu não acho que mereça uma "solução final".

Answer (score 0):

Queimem logo essas *tags*. Das alistadas nenhuma é realmente útil.

Comment: Acho que as tasg podem até ser discutidas em um mesmo debate, mas o problema não é só sumir com elas é impedir que criem novamente, se não passa um mês elas vão existir novamente, veja esta proposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tinha visto essa questão, obrigado.