# Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto

O [@Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5091/3635#comment18321_5091) citou:

> Ou poderia mudar a quantidade de reputação exigida para 1500, assim como no SOen: stackoverflow.com/help/privileges Acho que esse é o único privilégio que possui requisitos de reputação diferente aqui e no SOen.

Então aproveitei pra criar esta solicitação, no SOpt o minimo pra se criar uma tag é 300 pontos:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

No SOen o minimo é 1500 pontos:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

> O mais estranho é que [**criar sinônimos no SOpt**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) precisa de 2500 pontos, assim como é no [**SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Não estamos mais no *Beta* e nossa comunidade já possui um bom numero de pessoas perguntando, no entanto existem vários problemas devido a essa baixa reputação, por exemplo tags totalmente desnecessárias:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/130076/1

  > Eu sei que o autor já pegou as tags prontas, só peguei esse exemplo pra mostrar os lugares que estão sendo usadas

Outros problemas citados no meta:

- [Nós precisamos dessas tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5081/3635)
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5091/3635
- [Nome de Tag errado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5095/3635)

Esses é apenas um exemplo, estamos tendo vários assim ou piores, acho que aumentar a reputação necessária já ajuda a amenizar.

Um exemplo que vi hoje: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/135266/1

Tinha estas tags [login](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/login), [function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) e [deprecated](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deprecated), além de terem versões em português e inglês aqui no SOpt ao meu ver são tags totalmente inúteis, o qual geralmente já estão no contexto da duvida, acho que o uso melhor das tags são sobre tecnologias ou assuntos específicos.

Tag que notei hoje e que ao meu ver não faz sentido [carrinho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carrinho), isso não é uma tecnologia e não é uma "técnica especifica", exemplos de perguntas (já editei tudo):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/138180/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/80604/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/102959/revisions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/110819/revisions

Comment: Tem muita tag lixo por aí, mesmo, hehhehe

Comment: Acho que 750 já seria um bom número. Sei que estaria removendo esse privilégio de mim mesmo. Mas creio que vale a pena.

Comment: Sei que parece demorado de ganhar score @EMBarbosa mas levantar 1000 pontos é relativamente fácil pra alguns usuários, e justamente as vezes pode calhar de ser uma pessoa sem tanta atenção ou cuidado, por isso acho que acima de 1000 pode ser mais recomendável, eu mesmo conheço dois que tem 2k+ de score mas vivem cometendo gafes :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não discordo não... reputação no SO não é sinal de bom senso. Só quis dizer que já mudando pra 750 estaria removendo muitos casos, principalmente considerando que 100 pt de reputação podem vir por associação.

Comment: Incluindo os Sinônimos  +1;

Comment: 1500 acho que é razoável, mas o @Gabe deve ter estatisticas para ajudar a achar o ponto crítico e dar uma margem de segurança.

Comment: @DotNet engraçado que sinonimo já é exigido 2500, igual ao SOen :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não sabia, então tinha que ser bem mais. porque tem cada um ai que só por Deus.

Comment: @DotNet poderia mandar um exemplo de tag sinonimo com problema, se bem que ando sem esperança alguma de ajudar a melhorar a comunidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não lembro agora de um que vi, mas tem um que achei maio estranho [esse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/synonyms) do [winforms](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/synonyms) e ainda tem [Sinônimos sugeridos:](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsforms)

Comment: A sugestão de uma tag deveria ficar como _aguardando aprovação_ para que usuários com mais experiencia/pontos pudessem avaliar a qualidade e a necessidade dessas tags.

Comment: @DotNet esse [tag:window-forms] era uma tag normal antes foi o bfavaretto♦ que converteu em sinonimo (o que me pareceu correto), já a tag [tag:windowforms] ainda não foi convertida em sinonimo esta pra votação... resumindo, window-forms e windowform foram tags normais criadas devido a baixa reputação necessária para ser criar uma tag no site, então realmente é o problema dos 300 pontos :/

Comment: @Florida seria ótimo, infelizmente a curto prazo seria inviável, pois teria que se criar uma fila, um sistema e ainda ficarem vinculadas as perguntas que foram geradas, seria necessário uma série de procedimentos. Mas mesmo assim é otima ideia :)

Comment: Por favor aumentem logo, olha a tag [tag:aviso] que encontrei hoje

Comment: Eu vou discordar, pelo seguinte motivo temos poucos usuarios com tags especificas, vou citar o meu exemplo tag: postgresql-10 @Bacco que criou para mim, essa tag tem no soEN aqui ja foi usada 4 vezes de acordo com a lista abaixo, tags como leaflet foram criadas recetemente e outras muito uteis, e como seria como o novo sistema de 1500 pontos, pedi para os moderadores criarem?

Comment: @HudsonPH nem precisa ser moderador, qq usuário com os privilégios cria (talvez eu nem fosse mod quando criei essa que falou, é muita coisa pra lembrar). Note que você pegou um exemplo sem problema, mas não são todas assim. É normal é aparecer tag duplicada, tag redundante, tag de produto particular fora de escopo. De qq forma a idéia foi essa, trazer à tona pra comunidade opinar. - EDIT: nessa específica eu não estou no [histórico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/340127/revisions), talvez seja alguma outra (ou outra versão). O próprio texto foi aprovado por não-mods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Tradução livre de https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8807/1

Hoje estou alterando a reputação necessária para se criar novas tags para 1500.

Durante o ano passado:

- Das tags não excluídas...

  - Sete foram criadas por usuários com reputação maior que 1500.
  - Seis foram criadas por usuários com reputação menor que 1500.
- Das tags deletadas...

  - 25 foram criadas por usuários com reputação maior que 1500.
  - 58 foram criadas por usuários com reputação menor que 1500.
  - (Observe que usei a reputação *atual* dos usuários, portanto esses números podem não ser os mais precisos)

No total, foram criadas cerca de 100 tags. As tags visadas por essa alteração - tags excluídas que foram criadas por usuários com reputação menor que 1500 - compõem a maior parte das tags criadas no ano passado.

Minha única preocupação é que quase metade das tags que ainda estão por aí também não teriam sido criadas. Mas vejo benefícios suficientes para me sentir confortável testando esse novo limite. Sempre podemos alterá-lo novamente se vocês encontrarem problemas com esta nova configuração.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, @Augusto :)

Answer (score 12):

Bump.

Eu estava a remover certas tags de algumas perguntas mais cedo (peço desculpas se monopolizei a Home...). Comecei com uma única tag, mas no caminho vi várias para as quais não vejo necessidades. Por exemplo:

- [aspas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspas)
- [tratamento-erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tratamento-erro)
- [plugin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugin)

Não é a primeira vez que nos deparamos com várias tags sem noção. Existem ainda outros tópicos que listam mais tags sem noção. [Segue um exemplo recente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5664/podemos-remover-estas-tags).

Acho que a reputação mínima para criação de tags deveria ser maior. No mínimo igual à do SO, mas no nosso caso específico poderia ser maior ainda (5000, talvez).

Comment: Pior são as que são erros de digitação ou de ortografia mesmo, inclusive que repete a certa existente. Eu acho fundamental aumentar a barreira. Não resolverá tudo, mas já ajuda bem. Hoje já temos a maioria das tags necessárias, e sempre um usuário mais ativo pode criar uma nova para um novato quando ver a necessidade.

Answer (score 6):

Para tomar uma decisão sobre isto, primeiro é preciso ver o que poderíamos ter perdido. As seguintes 81 tags foram criadas por utilizadores com <1500 de reputação aquando da criação, durante os últimos 365 dias e presentemente em uso em pelo menos 2 perguntas:

```
Name                 Used User Link                 Created    RepOnCreation 
-------------------- ---- ------------------------- ---------- ------------- 
primaverabss         132  Sérgio Sereno             3/14/2018  360           
firebase-database    44   Rosário Pereira Fernandes 2/24/2018  315           
angular-5            33   Hebert Lima               2/20/2018  688           
efd-reinf            26   Pedro Gaspar              3/15/2018  312           
foreign-key          23   gabrielfalieri            3/1/2018   414           
inner-join           23   Geraldão de Rívia         6/19/2018  487           
jasminsoftware       19   Sérgio Sereno             3/14/2018  360           
object               19   Diego Henrique            4/25/2018  1278          
django-2.0           18   Guilherme IA              3/12/2018  883           
fragment             15   Max Fratane               3/13/2018  643           
bat                  13   VeroneseComS              10/25/2018 497           
firestore            13   Victor Pereira            7/24/2018  398           
adminlte             11   adventistaam              5/8/2018   1216          
dockerfile           11   Fábio Jânio               3/27/2018  1192          
tidyverse            10   Tomás Barcellos           6/29/2018  894           
keras                8    virtualdvid               4/13/2018  418           
escopo               7    Luiz Felipe               4/12/2018  953           
sefaz                7    Henrique Santiago         3/20/2018  530           
fusioncharts         7    adventistaam              4/23/2018  1184          
material             7    VeroneseComS              11/3/2018  479           
array-push           6    Florida                   5/1/2018   1446          
data-science         6    Leila                     10/31/2018 637           
try-with-resources   6    Douglas                   3/17/2018  643           
calendario           6    dark777                   3/13/2018  314           
grid-layout          5    Marcos de Andrade         3/27/2018  312           
newtonsoft           5    Bruno Richart             5/15/2018  414           
azure-devops         4    egomesbrandao             9/15/2018  1401          
restify              4    adventistaam              7/20/2018  1352          
dagger               4    Hugo                      3/19/2018  309           
dbeaver              4    Tássio Auad               3/23/2018  1144          
tempo-real           4    Luiz Felipe               2/23/2018  640           
vulnerabilidade      4    Luiz Felipe               2/27/2018  651           
comandos             3    Geraldão de Rívia         3/6/2018   319           
tela                 3    Luiz Felipe               3/11/2018  812           
relação              3    Luiz Felipe               3/16/2018  812           
google-play-services 3    Fernando VR               4/14/2018  716           
git-flow             3    Fábio Jânio               4/11/2018  1166          
glpi                 3    Murilo Gambôa             5/8/2018   1210          
flyway               3    Tiago Ferezin             5/8/2018   690           
.env                 3    adventistaam              7/20/2018  1352          
interceptor          3    VeroneseComS              7/23/2018  357           
weblogic12c          3    Tiago Leite               8/30/2018  698           
tomcat8              3    res                       6/29/2018  456           
rmarkdown            3    Flavio Silva              9/26/2018  500           
chatterbot           3    Mariana Ferreira          11/1/2018  543           
data-manipulation    3    Danilo Imbimbo            9/1/2018   305           
toasts               3    phpricardo                9/13/2018  406           
java-10              3    Marcelo                   5/20/2018  556           
removechild          3    Diego Henrique            6/3/2018   1480          
queue                3    braulio_holtz             11/30/2018 974           
next                 3    user4451                  6/13/2018  310           
snmp                 2    Iniciante                 1/16/2019  424           
leaflet              2    Leonardo Coelho           1/23/2019  417           
hudson               2    Gabriel Hardoim           2/7/2019   304           
analysis-services    2    Gustavo Hoppe Levin       6/12/2018  438           
previous             2    user4451                  6/13/2018  310           
catalina             2    Tiago Ferezin             5/21/2018  717           
cypher               2    Bruno Peres               5/18/2018  538           
sonarlint            2    res                       7/25/2018  864           
excellentexport      2    Rafael Weber              7/30/2018  445           
biometria            2    adventistaam              8/8/2018   1371          
webstorage           2    Hemerson Prestes          8/8/2018   354           
mysql-num-rows       2    Webster Moitinho          8/9/2018   318           
play-store-console   2    felipe.rce                8/16/2018  1019          
tapply               2    Tomás Barcellos           8/21/2018  932           
pkcs11               2    Henrique Santiago         8/28/2018  572           
weblogic             2    Tiago Leite               8/30/2018  698           
validation           2    Maykel Esser              9/13/2018  361           
função-discriminante 2    fsbmat                    9/1/2018   569           
matricial            2    Marcelo                   9/5/2018   708           
grafana              2    Bruno Wego                10/19/2018 1142          
tweepy               2    Gabriel Augusto           7/19/2018  324           
solaris              2    res                       6/28/2018  392           
colunas              2    Danilo Imbimbo            9/1/2018   305           
ncurses              2    Mário Feroldi             5/11/2018  506           
latin1               2    Marcelo                   4/25/2018  572           
nightwatch           2    guastallaigor             4/17/2018  342           
e2e                  2    guastallaigor             4/17/2018  342           
fedora               2    Leandro Macedo            4/6/2018   575           
socialite            2    Fábio Jânio               3/18/2018  1182          
fs                   2    Luiz Felipe               3/21/2018  833
```

Em contraste, estas 66 tags foram criadas por utilizadores com >=1500 de reputação aquando da criação (outra vez, durante os últimos 365 dias e presentemente em uso em pelo menos 2 perguntas):

```
Name                               Used User Link            Created    RepOnCreation 
---------------------------------- ---- -------------------- ---------- ------------- 
angular-6                          92   Marconi              6/1/2018   9140          
firebase-cloud-messaging           26   Pablo Almeida        2/21/2018  4572          
google-sheets                      20   Jefferson Alison     5/24/2018  2426          
uri-online-judge                   17   Isac                 11/11/2018 19729         
flutter                            11   Sorack               11/29/2018 17319         
keyframes                          11   hugocsl              3/6/2018   4085          
split                              9    Pena Pintada         4/17/2018  2300          
kivy                               9    jsbueno              10/9/2018  13492         
react-navigation                   9    LeandroLuk           10/4/2018  2422          
ipad                               7    Ivan Ferrer          4/20/2018  7743          
expo                               7    Felipe Duarte        5/14/2018  4527          
tempo-de-vida                      7    Maniero              4/9/2018   262752        
python-internals                   7    jsbueno              8/1/2018   11478         
falha-de-segmentação               7    Maniero              8/7/2018   282138        
linguagens-formais                 6    LINQ                 7/9/2018   51128         
c++17                              6    Maniero              7/10/2018  277547        
dev-tools                          6    hugocsl              9/10/2018  15603         
campos                             6    Maniero              10/29/2018 298826        
jsonobject                         5    Pena Pintada         4/16/2018  2298          
identity                           5    perozzo              5/11/2018  1820          
estatística-bootstrap              4    Bacco                5/17/2018  73315         
asp.net-core-web-api               4    Marconi              8/7/2018   9835          
postgresql-10                      4    Bacco                10/31/2018 81606         
spark                              4    DNick                9/14/2018  1980          
cli                                4    Maniero              7/5/2018   276837        
cpython                            4    Anderson Carlos Woss 8/1/2018   34229         
angular-7                          3    mutlei               2/6/2019   2697          
fetch                              3    Felipe Duarte        1/15/2019  4908          
camera                             3    Jasar Orion          11/15/2018 2059          
sweetalert2                        3    adventistaam         12/14/2018 1530          
spring-rest                        3    Tmc                  10/17/2018 2801          
user-interface                     3    hugocsl              10/25/2018 20761         
adonisjs                           3    Luiz Felipe          12/2/2018  2088          
lawtex                             3    Maniero              12/6/2018  305563        
telnet                             3    jsbueno              8/20/2018  11932         
mtv                                3    Wictor Chaves        7/25/2018  4241          
apache-kafka                       3    Barbetta             6/11/2018  2610          
prism                              3    ramaral              3/3/2018   35061         
pthreads                           3    Victor Stafusa       5/6/2018   44142         
jsonarray                          3    Pena Pintada         4/16/2018  2298          
database-partitioning              3    Guilherme            3/9/2018   1807          
webengine                          3    jsantos1991          2/22/2018  1811          
hoisting                           2    vnbrs                2/26/2018  8394          
lógica-difusa                      2    vnbrs                2/27/2018  8439          
clusterização                      2    gato                 4/4/2018   8483          
boletophp                          2    Fox.11               5/18/2018  2571          
scratch                            2    Homer Simpson        5/21/2018  2019          
apache-nifi                        2    Bruno César          6/21/2018  4952          
delphi-4                           2    David                6/21/2018  3008          
restsharp                          2    Leonardo Bonetti     7/26/2018  2869          
jalert                             2    adventistapr         8/21/2018  2224          
fabric.js                          2    Wallace Maxters      8/25/2018  53421         
sonarqube                          2    Maniero              8/28/2018  286903        
literal                            2    Maniero              8/30/2018  287259        
rvm                                2    Guilherme Nascimento 8/9/2018   73204         
protocol                           2    Maniero              8/17/2018  284588        
contratos                          2    Maniero              12/7/2018  305578        
delphi-5                           2    Roberto de Campos    11/5/2018  4614          
react-navigation-fluid-transitions 2    LeandroLuk           10/4/2018  2422          
face-detect                        2    Jasar Orion          9/24/2018  2049          
crop                               2    Jasar Orion          9/24/2018  2049          
php-internals                      2    jsbueno              9/25/2018  12775         
descriptors                        2    jsbueno              12/19/2018 14514         
java-11                            2    Articuno             1/5/2019   28441         
cte                                2    rbz                  11/20/2018 6476          
analise-de-texto                   2    Tomás Barcellos      1/17/2019  2441
```

Durante o mesmo período, 268 tags foram destruídas, ou por terem sido mescladas com outra tag, por não serem utilizadas em nenhumas perguntas, ou por serem usadas em apenas uma pergunta e não terem uma tag wiki a descrever o seu uso pretendido depois de 6 meses da sua criação. Não me é possível determinar quem as criou.

#### A Minha Recomendação:

Aumentar a reputação necessária para criar novas tags talvez não seja o mais prudente nesta altura. Se queremos tomar a decisão de restringir a habilidade de criar novas tags, então o resto dos utilizadores com o privilégio de as criar têm que ter a disponibilidade de as criar conforme for necessário — o que não aparente estar a acontecer, de momento, de maneira consistente: a maior parte das tags que acabaram por ser usadas mais do que uma vez em perguntas parecem ter sido criadas por utilizadores que deixariam de ser capazes de o fazer.

Em vez disso, activei um aviso (que aparentemente estava desactivado no SOpt) para quando um utilizador tenta criar uma nova tag:

[image: imagem]

Com sorte, isso ajuda a reduzir a criação de tags desnecessárias, repetidas, ou com erros ortográficos.

Comment: Praticamente todas tags criadas ali são ruins, desnecessárias ou mesmo erradas. Mas vamos ver o que acontece com o aviso, resolve parte do problema.

Comment: Grato por ativar, já é alguma coisa. Conhecendo um pouco o ritmo do site acho que aumentar a rep ainda seria uma boa, mesmo com o aviso (as tags criadas por < 1500 muito provavelmente teriam sido criadas por >= 1500 se o limite fosse maior, de qualquer maneira). Como é um recurso já existente, vai ser uma boa experiência. Ao menos a criação por "involuntariedade" vai ser eliminada. Agora poderemos saber quando é voluntário e quando não.