# Nome de Tag errado

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-específica

Pesquisei aqui e não achei nada relacionado a remoção de tag por estar errada, então vamos lá.

Temos a tag [delphi-xe10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe10), da qual essa versão do Delphi não existe, no caso deveria ser `DX` ou `Delphi-Seattle`.

Como procedemos?

Comment: \o/ ai tem bala na agulha ! :D

Comment: Pode ser que alguem faça a relação ao antigo Delphi-2010, dificil, mas é uma ótima escolha `Delphi-10`

Comment: Relacionado: [É possível excluir tags com erro de digitação?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1263/3117)

Comment: Ahhh @Math, então se houver uma próxima vez, então criamos a tag e aguardamos a exclusão automática... :D Obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra remover uma tag tem que editar todas as perguntas e remover uma a uma a tal tag, em alguns dias ou semanas o próprio sistema do site irá sumir com a tag do "autocomplete", ela ficará em um tipo de limbo (não me lembro ao certo, me corrijam se eu estiver enganado), o qual apenas moderadores tem acesso.

Como o AP não tem pontos o suficiente ele me ajudou a entender o que é o *Delphi 10* e a relação deste com o *XE*, também fiz uma boa pesquisa própria principalmente no site oficial.

Optei por usar a tag [delphi-10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10), pois no site do fornecedor do software o título mais expressivo é o mesmo (até pelo menos a data de hoje 24/05/2016), já editei todas perguntas para a nova tag, até mesmo perguntas sem a tag agora foi adicionado.

https://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/delphi

> ### Delphi 10
>
> Delphi is the most powerful Object Pascal IDE and component library
>   for cross-platform Native App Development with flexible Cloud services
>   and broad IoT connectivity. It provides powerful VCL controls for
>   Windows 10 and enables FMX development for Windows, Mac and Mobile.
>   Delphi is your choice for ultrafast Enterprise Strong Development™.
>   Look for increased memory for large projects, extended multi-monitor
>   support, improved Object Inspector and much more. Delphi is 5x faster
>   for development and deployment across multiple desktop, mobile, cloud
>   and database platforms including 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 10.

Aparentemente não faz diferença quando cita o Seattle (versão 10) ou Berlin (versão 10.1 e ultima atualização até o momento)

> **Atenção** deixo claro que não entendo de Delphi e só estou me baseando nas informações obtidas no site oficial, sinta-se livre pra discordar da escolha e sugerir novas alternativas de uso de tag

- A tag [delphi-xe10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe10) foi removida e logo irá desaparecer do sistema.
- Adicionei o fragmento para tag [delphi-10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10):

  > Utilize esta tag quando se o problema se referir ao Delphi que faz parte do *Rad Studio 10 Seattle* ou *Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin*
- Adicionei o wiki (usei o texto em inglês e tentei deixar o menos comercial possível, removendo termos como "o mais poderoso"):

  > Delphi 10 é uma *IDE* para *Object Pascal* e biblioteca de componentes
  >   para desenvolvimento de aplicativos nativos cross-platform, com os
  >   serviços em Cloud flexíveis e ampla conectividade com a *Internet das
  >   coisas*.
  >
  > Ele fornece controladores VCL (Visual Components Library) para Windows
  >   10 e permite o desenvolvimento FMX para Windows, Mac e Mobile.
  >
  > Suporta Windows 32bits e 64bits
  >
  > O uso da tag [delphi-10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10) pode se referir as versões do Delphi que
  >   vem acompanhado nos:
  >
  > - Rad Studio 10 Seattle
  > - Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin