# Faz sentido eu ter de ter 5 votos na tag para poder sugerir um sinónimo?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, tags

Faz sentido eu não poder sugerir um sinónimo de *tag* quando:

- Posso criar todas as *tags* que quiser
- Posso editar qualquer tag
- Posso aceitar/rejeitar edições de qualquer *tag*
- Posso editar qualquer publicação, com qualquer *tag*

Note-se que não é criar é apenas sugerir, ela ficará sujeita a validação.

Qual é então a razão para essa limitação?

Comment: Até faz. Se deveria já é outra coisa. No So faz mais sentido ainda e acho que lá deveria ter mesmo. Eu acho que poderia deixar sugerir em qualquer lugar a partir de determinada reputação, nem que seja alta. Tem coisas com muito mais potencial de acontecer algo errado se pessoas que não podem comprovar experiência na *tag* mexer em alguma coisa.

Comment: @bigown Eu só queria poder sugerir, sugerir não é mexer.

Comment: Sim, por isso eu disse que tem coisa pior que não é restrito.

Comment: @bigown. Ok, entendi. Tinha percebido mal o seu último parágrafo.

Comment: Se eu não me engano tem que ser 5 em uma ou mais respostas, perguntas não contam... Concordo contigo, duas restrições é dificultar muito sem necessidade.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216080/140010 (ou seja), pode ser mudado)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu não sei dizer porque isso ocorre, mas concordo com a premissa da pergunta. Eu diria até mais, logo abaixo.

Além dos itens já escritos na pergunta, é possível analisar algumas situações, fechar e até remover em *tags* que teoricamente não possui expertise. Claro. é só uma pergunta ou resposta, mas pode causar um problema.

Eu imagino que sugerir muitos sinônimos seja um problema no SO e este é o motivo principal. Mas em sites pequenos eu diria que o problema é ter poucas sugestões. Então já adianto que acho que deveria ser configurável por site e que aqui não tivesse esse limitação.

Eu poderia especular que foi criado assim no SO como uma forma de "proteger" a *tag* de pessoas que não entendem tanto do assunto. Mas me parece ir contra a filosofia do site que indica que as pessoas devem ser plurais. E novamente, como há outras coisa com menos limitação, parece ter ocorrido o que é comum em criação de legislação, onde uma parece ser mais restritiva do que outra porque foram criadas em situações diferentes, por pessoas diferentes, sem analisar o todo e perceber que em outro lugar não é tão restritivo. Um dos dois deveria mudar. Como nota paralela em site grande eu acho que as *tags* de maior movimento poderia exigir reputação nela para fazer certas ações e limitar os *badge hunters*.

## Mudanças

Iria até mais longe, permitiria sugestão de sinônimos com reputação geral mais baixa que a exigida atualmente, além de [aumentar um pouco a reputação para criar *tags*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/101), uma vez que isto acaba também sendo um problema.

Em sites pequenos acho até que exigir 5 apoiadores do sinônimo praticamente deixa para moderadores finalizarem o sinônimo se concordarem. Eu acho interessante que mais sinônimos possam ser sugeridos porque eles ajudam resolver um problema real.

## Alternativa

Como acho pouco provável que isso seja implementado no curto prazo, minha sugestão é usar meios alternativos. Pode postar aqui no meta (o que é meio burocrático) ou [entrar no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e pedir para um moderador analisar e criar um sinônimo (pode ser feito quase tão lacônico quanto usar o mecanismo oficial). Eu tenho feito por conta própria nos finais de semana (porque além de criar o sinônimo estou editando algumas perguntas para adequar a *tag*, assim evito sujar a página principal em dia de grande movimento).

## Organize!

Aproveito para convidar a todos para ajudar melhorar a organização do site não só sugerindo sinônimos, mas fazendo revisão em todas *tags* para achar erros. Além disso não esqueçam de editar perguntas para classificar melhor as perguntas. *Tags* devem indicar do que se trata a pergunta. Elas devem ser úteis para alguém procurar no futuro por *tags* específicas e achar perguntas relevantes dela, mesmo *tags* de baixa utilização, e não achar muita coisa misturada. Algumas por serem ambíguas têm muita coisa errada e serão bem difíceis arrumar (exemplo: [select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select)).

Comment: Não conseguiria dizer melhor aquilo que penso sobre o assunto.