# Podemos remover estas tags?

Tags: debate, tags

Olhando no histórico de tags recentementes criadas, encontrei as seguintes:

[override](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro), [import](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import), [tablet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablet), [ipad](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) e [settings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings)

todas com uma pergunta apenas.

Acredito que a maioria é totalmente descartável, principalmente as 3 ultimas, por nem fazerem parte do escopo do site, fora de um contexto, a tag erro também pode ser descartada por ser generica demais e não informar nada que ajude a localizar a pergunta.

o que acham, essas tags podem ser removidas ou devemos deixar elas ai no site?

Comment: Em situações semelhantes o que tenho feito é analisar cada pergunta para verificar se a tag se adequa, caso não removo-a. A tag, se não tiver perguntas durante algum tempo, será removida pelo sistema.

Answer (score 9):

Era pra ser comentário, mas...

Deixo para cada um argumentar ou dar sua opinião, mas no geral, concordo com algumas, outras não. Acho bom ter um certo consenso antes de se fazer alguma coisa. Minha experiência é que as pessoas não estão ligando muito pra isso. Há baixa participação nesses debates e muito pouco argumento útil sobre cada uma ser problema ou não, em geral só há opiniões. Tanto que eu comecei fazer, fiquei um pouco sem tempo para continuar e acabei perdendo a motivação porque não se chegava a nada útil. Ainda preciso bolar alguma coisa para tentar melhorar o uso de *tags*, principalmente onde trará mais benefício.

*Tags* com apenas uma pergunta costumam ser removidas pelo sistema em momento oportuno.

Nada impede de remover antes se elas realmente são inúteis.

Precisa ver em que contexto foram usadas. O fato de ter só uma não quer dizer que elas sejam ruins ou inúteis.

Comment: Então não há muito que fazer, a não ser esperar ne? Provavelmente essa pergunta vai ser "enterrada" como as outras que você citou foram e as tags vao ficar ai, por falta de um debate :/

Comment: Quais são as que você concorda (ou as que discorda)?

Comment: Provavelmente `tablet`, `ipad` e `erro` não estão sendo úteis, mas não vou cravar.

Comment: Concordo totalmente com a remoção dessas tags, que vc citou @bigown, principalmente com a tag `erro`, não vejo de que maneira ela poderia ser útil em algum momento, é algo muito abstrato e engloba praticamente todos os problemas, assim não tem sentido em utiliza-lá ao meu ver